# How to integrate over a timestep in a mass-spring model?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, spring, simulations

I'm writing a simulation of a block of matter using a "mass-spring" model, where the matter is modelled as a 3D lattice of point masses, where each point is connected by springs to the (up to) 26 neighboring point masses.

At each "tick" I calculate the new force at each point mass with (pseudocode):

```
for each neighbor:
    distance = length(vector_from_me_to_neighbor)
    force_here += spring_constant * (distance - ideal_distance_from_me_to_neighbor) * normalised_vector_from_me_to_neighbor
```

Using verlet integration, I update the position of each point mass with:

```
new_pos = current_pos + velocity_approximation + (force / point_mass) * timestep * timestep * 0.5;
```

(The timestep is between 16 and 32ms.)

This works reasonably for very "squishy" materials (with a low spring constant), but for stiffer materials the simulation explodes as the course timestep calculation bounces the masses back and forth further and further.

My question is, is there a resonably efficient way of integrating over the timestep rather than calculating the force once and applying it for the duration of the timestep?  Could I potentially use the first two terms of a taylor expansion?

Comment: You're missing a factor of (1/2) in your calculation of $\texttt{new_pos}$. Also, I assume you change the velocity as well, though you haven't mentioned it here. And lastly, do you have some plots of when your system works and when it doesn't that you could add here?

Comment: Is reducing the time step an option? Without doing too much numerical analysis I suspect there is a condition on your time step which roughly says that the distance each mass moves over a time step must be less than the separation between masses. For a high k the force will be higher and thus the time step must be smaller to enforce this condition.

Comment: Thanks for catching me missing the 1/2!

Comment: Yes the velocity_approximation is current_position - previous_position

Comment: I can't reduce the timestep enough to work on really stiff materials, but I could sample at a couple of points during the timestep and do an approximation based on that for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're running into the problem of [ODE stiffness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation), you have a system in which vastly different timescales need to be considered. There is an entire field of applied mathematics dedicated to the study of numerical ODE solvers, and it's not possible to discern exactly which method would suit you best from the information you've provided.

Your solver is what's known as an explicit method - the $n$th time step is calculated based solely on previous timesteps. Though simple to implement, such methods are intrinsically unstable when used with large time steps. It sounds like you need an implicit method instead. Look into something like the backwards Euler method. Note that this is not symplectic, so it does not conserve energy exactly, nor is it particularly accurate, but it is extremely stable.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensiove information - I will look at backwards Euler!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that before writing pseudocode, you try to master the underlying algorithm. If what you spelled *verlot* is supposed to be the Verlet algorithm, you miss the key ingredient that is the approximation for velocities. Moreover, the time-step should appear in your equation for new_pos.

Once you can implement [Verlet's algorithm in the *velocity* form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet), you may go quite far before you require implicit methods. In any case, do not waste your time with the backward Euler method. It is first-order, while Verlet is second order. Moreover, Verlet's algorithm is a symplectic method. In the numerical simulation of hamiltonian systems, this is a valuable bonus.

Comment: I appreciate that, although I have the simulation running (with an incorrect version of the algorithm!), and please excuse my spelling.